# Mysql to replace partial wildcard text

Tags: mysql

I have text in 2 different languages within various table fields. The languages are separated using []. So it goes like:

> [en]hello[/en][fr]bonjour[/fr]

I'm migrating to a new CMS which cannot read the 2 languages so I need to delete all of the French content in the database. Is there a MySQL query that will enable me to do this?

I've found lots of answers for updating a table to find and replace fixed values but can't find how to do it when the values are dynamic but always sandwiched between fixed values ([fr]*[/fr]).

To complicate things, there is no consistency in which language comes first within cells, sometimes it's French, other times its English.

Thanks very much for any help!

Comment: If you're using MariaDB 10, then you can use [`REGEXP_REPLACE()`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/regexp_replace/).

Comment: standard mysql regexes can only match. they cannot replace, they cannot capture. therefore you're stuck with plain string operations, which means you're almost certainly better off slurping your strings into client-side code (e.g php) and doing the splitting there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you're using MariaDB 10 (which has a [`REGEXP_REPLACE()`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/regexp_replace/) function), then you can try to hack something up with `LIKE`, `RLIKE`, and/or `SUBSTRING_INDEX`.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(data, '[fr]', 1) as new_data
FROM table
WHERE data LIKE '%[fr]%[/fr]%';
```

Comment: Thanks a million Rocket! That returns the new data perfectly. But how would I actually delete the %[fr]%[/fr]% content from the cells?

Comment: You could just change this to an `UPDATE` query.  `UPDATE table SET data = SUBSTRING_INDEX(data, '[fr]', 1) WHERE data LIKE '%[fr]%[/fr]%';`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this: update languages set lang = replace(lang, '[fr]bonjour[/fr]','')